# passenger-config restart-app returns 500 internal error without any error log entry

Tags: passenger, internal-server-error, application-restart, phusion

I recently updated my passenger phusion apache module to v5.0.21. Now, whenever I want to start/restart an app (e.g. via *passenger-config restart-app --ignore-app-not-running --ignore-passenger-not-running /var/www/apps/testapp/bundle*) I get the following:

```
srv:~# passenger-config restart-app
*** An error occured while querying the Phusion Passenger server:
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Length: 22
Content-Type: text/plain
Connection: close

Internal server error
```

According to the documentation there should be an error in the Apache error log but **there isn't**. The vhost error log is empty, the passenger app log is empty, all I get is that error from above.

- Rolling back to the previous version (5.0.7) didn't change anything
- passenger-status says "everything is fine"
- passenger-config  validate-install says "everything looks good"
- passenger-install-apache2-module says that it is installed correctly

I am running Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Did you also look in the global web server log (that is, not the vhost-specific one, and also not the Rails app one)? That is where Passenger logs errors. https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/apache/log_file/

Comment: Yes, that was the first one I had a look at.

Comment: Try increasing the Passenger log level to 5. Then run `passenger-config restart-app`, then look in the log file again. Do you see any interesting messages now?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I increased the log level and since then it didn't happen anymore. Weird... I will wait some more days...

Comment: I was just able to reproduce it. Passenger Phusion complains about another app not being there : 

[ 2015-11-19 23:31:19.1469 15587/7ff148c72700 age/Cor/ApiServer.h:524 ]: [Client A10] Exception: Cannot lstat("/var/www/apps/test123/prod/bundle/main.js"): No such file or directory (errno=2)

So all apps have to be there at any restart of any of these apps?

Comment: No, Passenger only restarts the app you told it to restart, and only during a restart can that error be triggered.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the hints, I actually had a PassengerLogFile defined per vhost which is not allowed. That resulted in the log being written to the latest deployed application which made debugging quite hard.

Eventually the whole thing only broke down whenever Apache restarted completely cause of one single project that was miss-configured. Eliminated, now everything works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We had the same error with `nginx <-> passenger <-> python`.
When trying to restart passenger, we got the same Error 500 without any information.

After searching for a while, simply restarting `nginx` fixed the issue !

Just in case this might help someone else :-)

Cheers